# How to manually create and wire a service at runtime to a component in typescript Angular 2

Tags: service, typescript, angular, components, factory-pattern

Here's my use case:

I have an interface with 4 different implementations `WorkflowA`, `WorkflowB`, `WorkflowC` and `WorkflowD`.

```
export interface IWorkflow {
  getQuestions(); 
  validateQuestions();
  getWorkflowSteps();
}
```

I have a `WorkflowManager` class that returns the appropriate workflow based on an input variable (Factory pattern?)

```
export class WorkflowManager {

  workflow:IWorkflow;

  getWorkflow(workflow){
    switch (workflow) {
      case 'workflowA':
        return new workflowA();
      case 'workflowB':
        return new workflowB();
      case 'workflowC':
        return new workflowC();
      case 'workflowD':
        return new workflowD();
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unrecognized workflow: ${workflow}`);
    }
  }

}
```

I also have a component `WorkflowComponent` that gets loaded

Example:
`/workflow=WorkflowA` loads `WorkflowComponent`. The component then extracts the routeparam `workflow` and based on the value, it then passes it to the `WorkflowManager` which returns the appropriate workflow.

Here's a snippet of my component

```
@Component({
 ...
})

export class Workflow implements OnInit {

  workflowInstance: IWorkflow;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private workflowManager: WorkflowManager,
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      let regType: string = params['workflow']; 
      this.workflowInstance = this.workflowManager.getWorkflow(workflow);
    });
  }

}
```

But I don't like the idea of manually instantiating `Workflow*` classes. How can I improve this so I wire it using Angular2 supplied API so that it can be managed/injected in to other components?

Also in my current implementation, I will have to make ajax calls outside of Angular framework which I don't think is the best thing to do.

Any ideas on how to take advantage of the Angular framework and improve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to inject an injector and acquire the workflow instance imperatively like:

```
@Injectable()
export class WorkflowManager {
  constructor(private injector:Injector) {}    

  workflow:IWorkflow;

  getWorkflow(workflow){
    switch (workflow) {
      case 'workflowA':
        return this.injector.get(workflowA);
      case 'workflowB':
        return this.injector.get(workflowB);
      case 'workflowC':
        return this.injector.get(workflowC);
      case 'workflowD':
        return this.injector.get(workflowD);
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unrecognized workflow: ${workflow}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can inject `workflowA`, `workflowB`, `workflowC`, `workflowA` and just return the right one depending on the `workflow` but I think using the injector is a better fit for this use case.

Ensure you provide `workflowA`, `workflowB`, `workflowC`.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway to further improve this by not instantiating everything but just the one that's needed everytime?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Above code only instantiates what is requested explicitly by the `workflow` parameter. If you would inject an instance over every using DI with constructor parameters, then it would instantiate all at once.

Comment: In   return this.injector.get(workflowA), is 'workflowA' (notice the small letter 'w' at the beginning of the word) an instance already declared in this class? How does angular pick WorkflowA class from 'workflowA' in   return this.injector.get(workflowA) statement? Thank you.

Comment: Again not sure what you mean. You use `new workflowA();` in the code in your question, therefore I assumed the class name is `workflowA` with lowercase `w`.

Comment: This way there is ever only one instance of a specific workflow, even when it is requested several times. Each workflow is created when first requested. If one is not requested at all, no instance is created.